# How to Show all Records from 2 access tables

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2013

I've been working on an access project to manage a local high school football league...

I have 2 tables:
tbl_schools, with the fields:

```
[id_school, school_name]
```

and
tbl_penalties, with the fields:

```
[id_penalty, school, player, match, card]
```

and a query, query_penalties:

```
SELECT DISTINCTROW tbl_penalties.school, Count(tbl_penalties.school) AS penalties
FROM tbl_penalties
GROUP BY tbl_penalties.school;
```

The Task/ My Question:
I need a query to show (on it's first column) all the schools in tbl_schools and (on it's second column) the number of times the school has been penalised, and 0 if the school hasn't got any penalty...

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT S.school_name
      ,COUNT(P.school) AS penalties
FROM tbl_schools S  LEFT JOIN tbl_penalties P
ON S.id_school = P.school
GROUP BY S.school_name
```

Comment: `count(*)` will always return > 0 , it should be `count(P.id_penalty)` to show 0 when the school doesn't have any penalties

Comment: Awesome, @FuzzTree, the count Tip was quite helpful.